# “Merci pour le m'expliquer” or “Merci pour l'expliquer à moi”?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, prépositions, compléments

What is the correct way to say

> Merci pour le m'expliquer
>   Merci pour l'expliquer à moi
>   ... ?

If there is a rule that helps me decide, I appreciate it too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither, the correct sentence is *Merci de me l'expliquer*.

You use *de* after *merci* when it's followed by a verb; *pour* when it's followed by a noun (*merci pour l'explication*).

The word order with [double pronouns](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/double-pronoun-order/) is *me + le*.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation lkl, was trying to upvote you but apparently I don't have enough points yet or something.  French sure has many rules that just need to be memorized it seems, way more than English; though perhaps if I were French and learning English I could say the same, I don't know.              EDIT: Would this also work: Merci de l'expliquer à moi?

Comment: @Jlente It wouldn't. The only way to use "à" this way is if you are namming someone: "Merci de l'expliquer à Matthieu". About upvote, you may not indeed, but you may "accept" the answer.